# Regex translation

Tags: regex, whitespace, uppercase

i need to translate this in regex:
I need to find uppercase word,space after the word and a "-" after the white space. Can anybody help me with this translation

Answer (score 0):

Though not sure what you mean by *translate*, this might be what you seek:
`/\b[A-Z]+\b -/`

Depends on your definition of *word*.

Or if uppercase means the first letter capitalized, use `/\b[A-Z][a-z]+\b -/`.

Comment: EXAMPLE: НОСИЛА - ако гледаш - ќе добиеш подарок, ако те носат - смрт, тешка болест. || In this sentence i need to remove the second "-" sign in the sentence. In the example between "носат - смрт" words

Comment: @Darko in that case, you need unicode support. Does your parser handle this? `\b[:upper:]+\b -`

Answer (score 0):

`[A-Z]+\s-` will match what I think you need. 1 or more uppercase letters, followed by a space followed by a minus sign. Depends on what you mean about uppercase word, I assume it's all uppercase letters.